# Using moment.js, How can I simplify a duration to its most simplified form?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using Moment.js to convert milliseconds to a duration :

`moment.duration(dur)`

and then output a string : `moment.duration(dur).toISOString()`

returns this : `PT15336H1S`

Obviously 15336 Hours is not a very useful number for a duration.

I have found a workaround to do this which is : `moment.duration(moment.duration(d)._data).toISOString()`

since `duration._data` returns a json object of this exact simplified form, 
passing it back into the constructor *does* correctly return the string I want. 
example :

```
var d = 55209601000; //milliseconds
var initialDuration = moment.duration(d)
console.log(initialDuration._data);
//{
// days:30,
// hours:0,
// milliseconds:0,
// minutes:0,
// months:8,
// seconds:1,
// years:1
//}
console.log(initialDuration.toISOString());
// "PT15336H1S"

var newDuration = moment.duration(initialDuration._data);
console.log(newDuration.toISOString());
// "P1Y8M30DT1S"
```

So obviously this method works, but it feels incredibly hacky. Surely there's a moment.js function or a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: "Obviously 15336 Hours is not a very useful number for a duration." What are you trying to accomplish here? toISOString returns the ISO8601 compliant string which does not require that hours/minutes/etc do not carry over https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Answer (score 0):

This is a hole (imho) in `momentjs`. Even using `humanize()` on your duration will give a not very specific `2 years`.

There is more detail in these two GitHub issues:

1. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463
2. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048

It seems like the popular opinion is just to install and use this plugin:

https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format